# Proving that $L = \{a^n b^m |\: m \:\%\: n = 0 \ \}$ is not context-free

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

For language $L = \{a^n\, b^m\: |\: m \:\%\: n = 0 \}$, that is,  is a multiple of .
I'm trying to find a proof that it isn't a context free. I know it isn't regular, but it also doesn't seem to be context-free to me. However, I am not sure how I would go about proving that it isn't context-free with pumping lemma. My quick attempt follows:

First, assume to contrary that  is context-free.
Let  be the guaranteed pumping length. Choose string $s\,=\,a^{\,n}\,b^{\,n}$, where $s\,\in\,L$. By the pumping lemma, we can write $s$ as $s\,=\,uvwxy$.

If $vx$ contains only occurrences of $a's$, then $uv^2wx^2y\:\not\in\:L$.

If $vx$ contains only occurrences of $b's$, then $uwy\:\not\in\:L$.

I can't do the third case instead.
If $vx$ contains some occurrences of $a's$ and $b's$.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: Your choice of $s$ can't work, because the language $\{a^n b^n \vert n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is context-free. You need to make use of the fact that $L$ contains words with longer sequences of $b$. Also, I don't think that analyzing $vx$ itself is particularly helpful: I think you'll need to handle the sub-cases where the boundary between the $a$s and the $b$s falls inside $v$, inside $w$ or inside $x$.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.  Could you explain me better or give an example please?  however this language is not 300% context free and I want to prove it

Comment: The part of the proof you've written so far also applies to the language $L' = \{a^n b^n\}$ which is context-free. You need to use the fact that $L$ also contains words like $a, abb, abbb, \ldots$. And I think you need to break down the analysis further: not just “$vx$ contains both $a$'s and $b$'s”, but “$v$ contains both $a$'s and $b$'s (and $w$ and $x$ only contain $b$'s)”, “$w$ contains both $a$'s and $b$'s”, “$x$ contains both $a$'s and $b$'s”.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. But I really don't know which string to start with and how to start :( ... It's too difficult in my opinion